# Big O notation of a constant

Tags: runtime, big-o, time-complexity

I calculate my runtime complexity to be **4**, what is the Big O notation of this?

For example if my runtime complexity is **4 + n** then its Big O = **O(n)**.

Comment: Constant runtime is generally denoted as `O(1)`, if it is that what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look loosely at the definition of what we mean by `f(n) is in O(g(n))`:

> `f(n)` is in `O(g(n))` means that `c · g(n)` is an upper bound on `f(n)`. Thus there
>   exists some constant `c` such that `f(n) ≤ c · g(n)` holds for
>   sufficiently large `n` (i.e. , `n ≥ n0` for some constant `n0`).

You can treat a constant function just as any other function, w.r.t. analysing its asymptotic behaviour using e.g. big-O notation.

```
f(n) = 4
g(n) = 1

f(n) ≤ c · g(n) = c · 1, for c ≥ 4 and for all n           (*)

     (*) with e.g. n0=0 and c=4 => f(n) is in O(1)
```

---

Note: as Ctx notes in the comments below, `O(1)` (or e.g. `O(n)`) describes a *set of functions*, so to be fully correct, `f` should be described to be in `O(1)` (`f ∈ O(n)`, `f`:s set membership in `O(1)`), rather than *"`f(n)` being in `O(1)`"*. You can, however, probably expect to see the less rigorous version *"`f(n)` is in `O(1)`"* (or some `O(g(n))`) just as frequently at the web, at least outside of the scope of scientific articles.

Comment: Understand it now much better than in lecture , thanks

Comment: To be pedantic: f is in O(1), since O(1) is a set of functions

Comment: @Ctx You are right, thanks. Although it might possibly confuse less math-inclined readers to omit function arguments, so I'll simply up vote your comment and add a small reference to it in the answer. Thanks.