# Why this code gives big-O = O(1)

Tags: big-o

```
public static LinkedList third(int[] array){
    LinkedList retval = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 999 && i < array.length; i = i + 1) {
        retval = new LinkedList(array[i], retval);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Why this code gives big-O = O(1) ?

Comment: Maybe because i is not more 999, but it should be O(999)

Comment: It "_should"_ not be `O(999)` (redundant notation); `O(999)` reduces naturally to `O(1)` if analysing this algorithm---just like any other---using the formal definition of Big-O-notation. To OP: see e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35278078/4573247) for "formally" analysing a the asymptotic behaviour of a constant function (an analysis that is, in itself, quite redundant, however possibly valuable for learning). Replace `f(n) = 4` with `f(n) = 999` in the linked answer, and you'll swiftly reach the conclusion that your algorithm above runs in constant time, i.e., `O(1)`.

Comment: Thank you so much.You help me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the loop will be executed maximally 999 times which is a constant value therefore You can think of it as it's O(999) = O(1) = O(c), where c is a constant value.

If the value of `i` wouldn't be limited by 999, the loop would be executed `array.length` times and the complexity would be O(n), where n is the size of input array.