# How to prove a constant is O(1)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

How would you possibly show that 2 is O(1)?

More over, how would you show that a constant is theta(1) hence omega(1) and O(1)?

For O, I am under the impression that you are able to do a simplification for f(n), whereby it can be reduced down to 1, but then how can this prove that 2 is O(1) for some n0? What would be the n0 value in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O notation of a constant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277887/big-o-notation-of-a-constant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a function *f* is in O(1) if there exist constants *n*<sub>0</sub> and *M* such that *f*(*n*) ≤ *M* · 1 = *M* for all *n* ≥ *n*<sub>0</sub>.

If *f*(*n*) is defined as 2, then just set *M* = 2 (or any greater value; it doesn't matter) and *n*<sub>0</sub> = 1 (or any greater value; it doesn't matter), and the condition is met.

> […] that 2 is O(1) for some n0? What would be the n0 value in this case?

*n*<sub>0</sub> is not a parameter here; it's not meaningful to say "O(1) for some n0". You can arbitrarily choose *any* value of *n*<sub>0</sub> that makes *f* satisfy the condition; if one exists, then *f* is O(1), period.

Comment: Is it also the case that 2 is Big-Theta(1)?

Comment: @Sam11112: Yes, for the same reason (and by the same sort of argument).

Answer (score 0):

Big Oh and Theta so not indicate the time taken by an algorithm. They indicate the **rate of increase in time as the input increases** for the algorithm. When you understand this, things become very easy and less mathematical. *f(x) = 2 {for all and any x}* is always O(1) since the output value (2) does not depend on the input value (x) at all! O(1) represents this independence. So does theta(1) and omega(1).

Comment: I understand it better if you introduce mathematics.

Comment: Then the answer should be pretty clear! f is a function independent of the value of x. So it can be reduced to a single point (2, in your case) for a given series of x values. Since there can be no order of change for a point, it falls under O(1) asymptomatically